# LWUIT: Load images in background thread

Tags: java, multithreading, lwuit

I have a list that contains about 20 image URLs and some other things.

I want to display the other things (description) and allow the user to interact with the app while I load the 20 images.

What I noticed is that no matter what I tried, I can't interact with the form until the images finished loading even though I am doing the loading in another thread.

This is my solution I am using now.

```
private Container createServerItems() throws Exception {
    Container list = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    final int size = mediaList.size();

    final Button buttons[] = new Button[size];

    System.out.println("In here: " + size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        Container mainContainer = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        Media m = new Media();
        m.fromJSONString(mediaList.elementAt(i).toString());

        buttons[i] = new Button("please wait");

        final int whichButton = i;
        Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println(MStrings.replaceAll(m.getImgURL(), "\"", ""));
                    final StreamConnection streamConnection = (StreamConnection) Connector.open(MStrings.replaceAll(m.getImgURL(), "\"", ""));                        
                    Image image = Image.createImage(streamConnection.openInputStream());
                    streamConnection.close();

                    buttons[whichButton].setText("");
                    buttons[whichButton].setIcon(image.scaled(32, 32));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        });
        TextArea t = new TextArea(m.getDesc());
        t.setEditable(false);
        t.setFocusable(false);
        t.setGrowByContent(true);

        mainContainer.addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST, buttons[i]);
        mainContainer.addComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER, t);

        list.addComponent(mainContainer);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: There is no need to contact me personally to answer your questions. Vimal gave a perfectly good answer here.

Comment: I was desperate, sorry. I have a deadline to meet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**APPROACH I :** *LWUIT 1.5* has a powerful *LWUIT4IO* library to address your problem.

An excerpt from [Shai's Blog link](http://www.lwuit.com/2011/08/parsing-in-lwuit-lwuit4io.html)

> A feature in **LWUIT4IO** to which I didn't give enough spotlight is the
>   cache map, its effectively a lean hashtable which stores its data
>   using weak/soft references (depending on the platform) and falls back
>   to storage when not enough memory is available. Its a great way to
>   cache data without going overboard. One of the cool things about it is
>   the fact that we use it seamlessly for our storage abstraction (which
>   hides RMS or equivalent services) in effect providing faster access to
>   RMS storage which is often slow on devices.

Another useful link is [here](http://www.lwuit.com/2010/08/introducing-lwuit-for-io-lwuit4io.html)

The idea is to delegate the Network IO functionality to a singleton to avoid any UI deadlocks, like the one you are facing.

A very good video demo [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FXhlghkgsHE) by vprise, explains how to bind GUI functionality to your netbeans. In this video at around 7:00 mins it explains the use of `ImageDownloadService` class which binds the component to its thumbnail url which will seamlessly fetch from the network and populate the Image.

**APPROACH II:** Difficult one of create custom logic

1. Create a singleton that will interface with the network to fetch the
   data
2. Use a queue to handle the sequential image download services
3. Create a new thread for this singleton and wait on the queue.
4. With each image download service bind a listener with the invoking
   component so that it easier to update the right component.

Comment: This works alright, I used connectionRequest, my bandwidth is too small can't want the video. I have a question though, How do I handle errors, for example, in case of 404 or space in URL, a dialog box is displayed, I want to suppress this and handle these errors myself. Some images might not be available (so a 404 is expected) I don't want a dialog box popup every time this happens.

Comment: Good that you were able to solve the main question of this post. 

To address your other questions 
(a) for spaces in url you can pass your url through a function that decides whether to remove spaces or convert it to `+` the `url enncoding` form of space

(b) For 4XX errors, in `ConnectionRequest` class check `handleException(...)` and `handleErrorResponseCode(...)`, override these methods, *I PERSONALLY DON'T ADVISE IT, DO IT ON YOUR DISCRETION*, to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 1):

According to the lwuit spec,     callSerially() executes on the Event Dispatch Thread, which means that it will block other events until it completes.  You need to move your code to load the image outside of that method and keep only the setText and setIcon calls in callSerially().